# Dropdown menus inluding dates ( From Date1 To Date2 ) in PysimpleGUI

Tags: list, date, datetime, combobox, pysimplegui

Dears,

I am looking for a PysimpleGUI way to create dropdown menus which includes range of dates ( only years) , instead of writting the whole list in sg.combo () function or instaed of Choosing Sg.CalendarButton, which are both not useful in my case :

I want something like the below :

```
import PySimpleGui as sg
sg.Combo([range(Date1 To Date2)], size=(6, 1), font=("Helvetica", 10), key='Dates'),)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[range(Date1 To Date2)]` is a `list` with only one item which is is a class of immutable iterable objects.

Example Code

```py
import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def date(year, month=1, day=1):
    return datetime.date(year, month=month, day=day)

def get_years(start, stop):
    return list(range(start.year, stop.year+1))

start = date(2022)
stop  = date(2030)
dates = get_years(start, stop)
layout = [[sg.Combo(dates, font=("Helvetica", 10), size=(5, 5), enable_events=True, key='Dates')]]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    item = values['Dates']
    print(item, ":", type(item))

window.close()
```

```py
2024 : <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason Yan. I'm trying to use dates showing only years as I mentionned in description and it's reporting an error :
start = datetime.date(2000)
stop  = datetime.date(2022)
Error : TypeError: function missing required argument 'month' (pos 2)
How to limit that items to only years ? Thanks

Comment: Update as above.

Comment: Excellent !!! THanks a lot @Jason for your usual Support